AWS Control Tower- You must unsubscribe your organization from AWS config
I get this message "You must unsubscribe your organization from AWS config " while configuring the landing zone in my account.
Can someone please help what will happen if I disable the config rule in my existing organisation, I have many rules attached, will they stop working?
